# error when exporting app using proguard

Tags: android, proguard

My Application compiles completely fine without proguard. but when i try to use proguard to obfuscate my code I get an error I couldn't fix for the life of me.

i tried

```
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
```

and a variety of keeps to no avail.
I'm using greenDao library and adding suggested -keep from greenDao FAQ didn't help either. the following error persists:

```
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator: can't find referenced class freemarker.template.Configuration
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator: can't find referenced class freemarker.template.Configuration
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator: can't find referenced class freemarker.template.Configuration
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator: can't find referenced class freemarker.template.DefaultObjectWrapper
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator: can't find referenced class freemarker.template.DefaultObjectWrapper
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator: can't find referenced class freemarker.template.Configuration
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator: can't find referenced class freemarker.template.Configuration
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator: can't find referenced class freemarker.template.Template
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator: can't find referenced class freemarker.template.Template
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator: can't find referenced class freemarker.template.Template
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator: can't find referenced class freemarker.template.Template
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator: can't find referenced class freemarker.template.Template
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator: can't find referenced class freemarker.template.Template
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator: can't find referenced class freemarker.template.Template
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator: can't find referenced class freemarker.template.Template
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator: can't find referenced class freemarker.template.Template
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator: can't find referenced class freemarker.template.Configuration
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator: can't find referenced class freemarker.template.Template
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator: can't find referenced class freemarker.template.Template
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator: can't find referenced class freemarker.template.Template
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator: can't find referenced class freemarker.template.Template
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator: can't find referenced class freemarker.template.Template
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: net.sf.andpdf.crypto.RC4Cipher: can't find referenced class org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.RC4Engine
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: net.sf.andpdf.crypto.RC4Cipher: can't find referenced class org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.RC4Engine
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: net.sf.andpdf.crypto.RC4Cipher: can't find referenced class org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.RC4Engine
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: net.sf.andpdf.crypto.RC4Cipher: can't find referenced class org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.RC4Engine
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: net.sf.andpdf.crypto.RC4Cipher: can't find referenced class org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: net.sf.andpdf.crypto.RC4Cipher: can't find referenced class org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: net.sf.andpdf.crypto.RC4Cipher: can't find referenced class org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.RC4Engine
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: net.sf.andpdf.crypto.RC4Cipher: can't find referenced class org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.RC4Engine
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] Warning: there were 30 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid]    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid]    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid]    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2015-08-11 22:11:38 - SubClientAndroid]    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the -dontwarn option.

```
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.crypto.**
-dontwarn freemarker.template.**
```

Comment: thanks this worked, one question though. simply shutting the warnings won't have any negative effects in my application? like runtime crashes in specific places where the said files may be used? since they're libraries I simply don't know their inner work.

Comment: That does not affect your code. It simply says that it cannot check the references.